# Graph paper with elongated grid sections?

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawingbrush

I am trying to make some Graph Paper using WPF using the `DrawingBrush`.

I found the following example on MSDN which is pretty close to what I want but not exactly. I want to do this is pure XAML. I am fairly new to WPF.

```
 <DrawingBrush x:Key="GridTile" 
                  Viewport="0,0,10,10" 
          ViewportUnits="Absolute"
          TileMode="Tile">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,0.1, 0,0.1Z" Brush="Blue" />
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L0,1 0.1,1, 0.1,0Z" Brush="Red" />
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

**Currently this generates**

[image]

**I want to generate**

with a width of 3cm and each row being 4mm

[image]

I will use this tile my background or rather the `DrawingBrush` `TileMode` takes care of that for me.

Comment: That pattern creates a tiled grid pattern. The reason it looks stretched is because of your container. What object are you using the brush on?

Comment: @Cyral thanks for responding. The picture is from an image I have been given. Its not generated by WPF. What I want to do is create the same image but using wpf.

Comment: Oh, that code you supplied works fine, do you just need to know what to do with it? EDIT: You mean you want the vertical lines to be closer?

Comment: @Cyral exactly ... Vertical lines need to be 1mm apart and horizontal 4mm apart ... that would be super helpful!!!

Comment: Using milimeters is another topic, see [How to specify WPF control size in millimeters using XAML](http://developernote.com/2012/10/how-to-specify-wpf-control-size-in-millimeters-using-xaml/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the size of the `Brush` so the `Viewport` has more height than width, and change the `Geometry` accordingly so the lines still appear `1px` thick.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WPF" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DrawingBrush x:Key="GridTile" Viewport="0,0,4,16" 
                      ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,0.05 0,0.05Z" Brush="Black"/>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L0,1 0.1,1 0.1,0Z" Brush="Black"/>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Rectangle Height="512" Width="512" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0"
               Fill="{StaticResource GridTile}"/>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Cyral what you have done is really awesome,  I am trying to get something closer to the above image (I updated it) with the dark borders to create sections 12mm x 30mm. Is it possible to help me complete this final step or just advice and I will go about it myself?